# Wait and Notify Methods in Synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait, notify

So my project is a card type simulation. I have a Dealer, Player, and Heap class. The heap is a shared resource where the dealer places one(not multiple, just one) card and the player will pick it up. I create two threads, one for a Dealer and one for a Player. The dealer is supposed to wait until he is notified that the player has picked up the card; then he will proceed to place a new card down. Similarly, the Player will wait until he is notified that the dealer has placed a card down, and then the Player will pick the card up.

There is also supposed to be a mechanism that both the Player and the Dealer will use to confirm that they are allowed to put or take a card from the Heap. I used a boolean; if the boolean is true or false, the Player or the Dealer could or could not be allowed to do their corresponding actions.

In the mean time, the Player and the Dealer are set to sleep for a random time interval, when they will then wake up and check to see if they can run their actions. If they cannot, they would wait until they are notified.

My question involves the wait and notify methods. What is the difference between wait and sleep? How would I make is to that the Player/Dealer would wake up from a sleep, and they are forced to wait until they are notified, if they are not allowed to take/add a card from the heap? Also, am I even doing the synchronization properly?

Sorry that my code is really messy. Please ask for clarifications.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Heap {

    static String topCard;

    static boolean newCardChecker = false;

    public Heap(){

    }

    public synchronized static void putOnHeap(String Card){  
        topCard = Card;
        newCardChecker = true;
    }

    public synchronized static String takeFromHeap(){
        newCardChecker = false;
        return topCard;
    }

}






import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dealer implements Runnable {

String[] deck = {"2 Hearts", "3 Hearts", "4 Hearts", "5 Clubs", "6 Clubs", "7 Clubs",
                "8 Hearts", "9 Hearts", "10 Hearts" , "10 Spades"}; 

ArrayList<String> myHand = new ArrayList<>();

Heap theHeap;

public Dealer(Heap heap){
    theHeap = heap;

    for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++){ //adds deck to dealer's hand
        myHand.add(deck[i]);
    }

}


public void run(){      

    //synchronized(theHeap){
    while(myHand.size() != 0){ //repeat until dealer's hand is empty

            if(Heap.newCardChecker != false){
                try{
                    Thread.currentThread().wait();                    
                }catch(InterruptedException e){                    
            }
                theHeap.putOnHeap(myHand.get(0));
                System.out.println("Placed card " + myHand.get(0) + " onto heap");
                myHand.remove(0); //although dealer's cards in hand  is being removed, the dealer had
                                  //the same cards as deck so I print out the deck contents at the end
                Thread.currentThread().notify();
            }

        try{
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000 + (int)Math.random() * 10000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){      
        }

    }
    //}

    System.out.println("Hello, I am a dealer. Here is my hand: " + Arrays.deepToString(deck));
}
//While not last card, put a card on heap. sleep for a rand time
//print "put card x on heap"

public static void main(String[] args){
    Heap heap = new Heap();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Dealer(heap));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Player(heap));
    //Thread t3 = new Thread(new Heap());

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

}

```
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class Player implements Runnable {

ArrayList<String> myHand = new ArrayList<String>();
Heap theHeap;

public Player(Heap heap){
    theHeap = heap;
}

public void run(){

    //synchronized(theHeap){
    while(myHand.size() != 10){

        try{
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000 + (int)Math.random() * 10000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){      
        }

        if(Heap.newCardChecker != true){

            try{
                Thread.currentThread().wait();                    
            }catch(InterruptedException e){    
                //System.err.println("Exception caught");
            }

            myHand.add(theHeap.takeFromHeap());
            System.out.println("Took card " + myHand.get(myHand.size() - 1) + " from heap");
            Thread.currentThread().notify();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Hello, I am a player. Here is my hand: " + myHand.toString());
    }




//}
//While less than or equal to 10 card, take card from heap. Then sleep.
//"print took card x from heap"
```

}

Comment: Generally speaking using low level synchronization primitives is a sign that you might be doing it wrong. Instead consider reading about the members of the java.util.concurrent package. If I were trying to write the program you have described I would create a single threaded ExecutorService and have it run Tasks as they come up. No need for wait and notify here.

Comment: My teacher says it is possible to use wait and notify. I am probably just doing the synchronization wrong(I don't really have a full grasp of it). How do you think this could be solved?

Comment: I tend to be of the opinion that students should not post their homework assignments on stackoverflow. I encourage you to read the documentation and your text book and post back here if you have a very specific question rather than a request to do your homework.

Comment: Okay. It's just that I've been stumped on this problem this past weekend. Is it possible to do synchronization with two different classes and using the wait/notify with only creating and starting the threads in the main, and nothing else in there? Is it possible to have everything in the run methods?

Comment: Part of why this is so hard for you to figure out is that the problem is _not_ a good example of how to use threads.  According to your rules, the "player" and the "dealer" strictly take turns:  There's nothing for the player to do but wait() when it's the dealer's turn, and vice versa.  If I had to write that code to solve some real-world problem (i.e., not a learning exercise), then I would use just one thread with a loop that alternately called a playersTurn() function and a dealersTurn() function.

Comment: @noobforce Yes, it is possible to code all the higher order synchronisation patterns (semaphore, countdown latch, blocking queue) using only `wait()` and `notify()`. But it's tricky and very easy to get it wrong. I would for example put all synchronization and waiting/notification in the `Heap` class because at the moment there's nothing guaranteeing that `Heap.newCardChecker` will be checked before putting or taking a card, and even where it is checked, there's no guarantee that you'll see the most up-to-date value.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem would be to make the `Heap` be an ArrayBlockingQueue with a fixed-capacity of one element.  The `Dealer` would simply loop `put()`ting cards onto the heap, and the `Player` would loop, `take()`ing cards from the heap.

The Dealer would automatically block (i.e., wait) in the `put()` call whenever the heap already had a card in it, and the Player would block in the `take()` call whenever the heap was empty.

You could put `sleep()` calls into either loop to simulate the Dealer and the Player taking time.

---

Regarding the difference between `sleep()` and `wait()`;

You could achieve the exact same effect as `sleept(t)` by calling `foo.wait(t)` on an object `foo` that never gets notified.  So, *technically*, `sleep()` is redundant:  We could all get along without it.

But names are important.  When I see `foo.wait()` in a program, I expect that the caller is waiting for some other thread to do something related to the `foo` object, and when I see `sleep()` I know that the caller is just killing some time.